# A continuous extension of a function $f:A\to A $ where A is open.

Tags: general-topology

Let $A \subset S \subset \mathbb{R}^n $ such that $A, S$ are open.
$ A $ is also bounded.
Let $f:A\to A$ be continuous.
Is it possible to extend $f$ to $f':S\to S$ such that $f'\mid_A = f$ and that $f'$ is continuous?
If so, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x)=( \sin(1/x)+2)/4$ gives a counterexample on $A=(0,1)$ and any neighbourhood $S$ of $A$.